# Behaviour difference using Python pickle module

Tags: python, pickle

I'm developping a python app that deals with big objects, and to avoid filling the pc ram while executing, I chosed to store my temporary objects (created at one step, used by the next step) in files with pickle module.
While trying to optimize memory consumption, I saw a behaviour that I don't understand.

In the first case, I'm opening my temp file, then I loop to do the actions I need and during the loop I regularly dump objects in the file. It works well, but as the file pointer remains open, it consumes a lot of memory. Here is the code example :

```py
tmp_file_path = "toto.txt"

with open(tmp_file_path, 'ab') as f:
    p = pickle.Pickler(f)
    for filepath in self.file_list:  // loop over files to be treated
        try:
            my_obj = process_file(filepath)
            storage_obj = StorageObj()
            storage_obj.add(os.path.basename(filepath), my_obj)        
            p.dump(storage_obj)
            [...]
```

In the second case I'm only opening my temp file when I need to write inside it :

```py
tmp_file_path = "toto.txt"

for filepath in self.file_list:  // loop over files to be treated
    try:
        my_obj = process_file(filepath)
        storage_obj = StorageObj()
        storage_obj.add(os.path.basename(filepath), my_obj)
        with open(tmp_file_path, 'ab') as f:
            p = pickle.Pickler(f)
            p.dump(storage_obj)
        [...]
```

The code between the two versions is the same except from the block :

```py
with open(tmp_file_path, 'ab') as f:
            p = pickle.Pickler(f)
```

which moves inside/outside the loop.

And for the unpickling part :

```py
with open("toto.txt", 'rb') as f:
    try:
        u = pickle.Unpickler(f)
        storage_obj = u.load()
        while storage_obj:
            process_my_obj(storage_obj)
            storage_obj = u.load()
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

When I'm running both codes, in the first case I have a high memory consumption (due to the fact that temp file remains open during the treatment I guess) and in the end, with a set of inputs, the application finds 622 elements in the unpickled data.

In the second case, memory cunsumption is far lower, but in the end , with the same inputs, the application finds 440 elements in the unpickled data, and sometimes crashes with random errors during Unpickler.load() method (for exemple Attribute error, but it's not always reproductible and not always the same error).

With even bigger set of inputs, the first code example often crashes with memory error, so I'd like to use the second code example, but it seems that it doesn't succeed to save all my objects correctly.

Does anyone have an idea of the reason why there is differences between the two behaviour ?
Maybe opening / dumping / closing / reopening /dumping / etc a file in my loop doesn't garanty the content that is dumped ?

**EDIT 1 :**
All the pickling part is done in a multiprocessing context, with 10 processes writing in their own temp file, and the unpickling is done by the main process, by reading each temp file created.

**EDIT 2 :**
I can't provide a full reproductible example (company code), but the treatment consists of parsing C files (process_file method, based on pycparser module) and generating an object representing the C file content (fields, functions etc) -> my_obj. Then storing my_obj in an object (StorageObj) that has a a dict as attribute, containing the my_obj object with the file is was extracted from as key.

Thanks in advance if anyone finds the reason behind this, or suggest me a way around to avoid this :)

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? There are several key parts here that we know practically nothing about. For example, what is ``StorageObj`` and what does ``storage_obj.add(os.path.basename(filepath), my_obj)`` do? What is ``ast_storage``?

Comment: "All the pickling part is done in a multiprocessing context, with 10 processes writing in their own temp file"  This could be a source of error too, please include your multiprocessing code. Do you ever have different processes writing to the same pickle file? If so that's very likely leading to corruption in both cases, but more so in the second case.

Comment: Each process has its own file, and during execution I see that each of my 10 temp files are filled with dumped data. So corruption (if there is some) doesn't from that.
I will edit the post to add more details about the treatment.

Comment: A [mcve] does not mean you post all or even *any* of your actual code. It means you post *some* code which is short (minimal) and exhibits the same problem (reproducible). This code may or may not be directly derived from your actual code.

Comment: "_as the file pointer remains open, it consumes a lot of memory_". Please define "a lot of memory". And why do you think it is caused by the open file? I do not expect an open file to consume a lot of memory. It seems far more likely that your problem is caused by the multiprocessing code, as others have suggested as well. Could you reproduce this problem in a [mre] with arbitrary (but similar) data? For example, instead of actually reading input files, create a dictionary or custom class of approximately the same size and see what happens. This uses "divide and conquer" to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the file. It is that you are using a common Pickler which is retaining its memo table.

The example that does not have the issue creates a new Pickler with a fresh memo table and lets the old one be collected effectively clearing the memo table.

> But that doesn't explain why when I create multiple Pickler I retrieve less data than with only one in the end.

Now that is because you have written multiple pickles to the same file and the method where you read one. Only reads the first. As closing and reopening the file resets the file offset. In the reading of multiple objects each time you call load advances the file offset to the start of the next object.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem by using big arrays, and in this case when I use both methods the output is the same.
Can the offset problem be linked to my specific data type ? 
If yes do you have in mind some workaround to avoid this problem ? 
I also tried to see if there was any incoherences in file offset while runing the code with File.tell() method but I didn't notice anything unusual